# Laravel logout redirect not working

Tags: php, laravel, http-redirect, laravel-routing

Im trying to figure out the reason why my controller action is not performing a redirect like intended.

When i click my logout action, it's supposed to terminate a user session and redirect to the home page but it's redirecting to the admin/logout action.

```
//controller
public function getLogout()
{
     Auth::logout();
     return Redirect::route('/');
}



//routes
Route::controller('admin', 'AdminController');
Route::controller('/', 'HomeController');



//blade
{{ HTML::linkAction('AdminController@getLogout','Logout') }}
```

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is that laravel requires the user table to have a remember_token, which is used to avoid cookie hijacking.

Simply add a nullable 100 character field in your users table called "remember_token" and run the migration.

A good reminder of this would be seen in the default users model because the field is already defined.

Please view link for more information: http://laravel.com/docs/upgrade#upgrade-4.1.26

```
public function getRememberToken()
{
    return $this->remember_token;
}

public function setRememberToken($value)
{
    $this->remember_token = $value;
}

public function getRememberTokenName()
{
    return 'remember_token';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you could use [named routes](http://laravel.com/docs/routing#named-routes) :

```
Route::get('/', array('as' => '/', 'uses' => 'HomeController@index'));
// Replace 'index' with the method you want.
```

And then in your controller :

```
return Redirect::route('/');
```

Or with your current route, this may work :

```
// Define the route
Route::controller('/', 'HomeController');
// Controller
return Redirect::to('/');
```

Answer (score 1):

Your route:

```
Route::get('/', array('as' => 'home', 'uses' => 'HomeController@index'));
```

Then your blade:

```
{{ link_to_route('home','Home')}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
{{ HTML::linkAction('HomeController@getLogout','Logout') }}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Redirect::to();
```

and in routes

```
Route::get('HomeController@getLogut', 'logout');
```

link like this

```
<a href="/logout">Logout</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because when you are using `Redirect::route()` you are supposed to include the route name. See the [Laravel API](http://laravel.com/api/class-Illuminate.Routing.Redirector.html#_route).

Otherwise if you still want to go and redirect to `/` without defining its route name. You could instead use `Redirect::to()`

```
public function getLogout()
{
     Auth::logout();
     return Redirect::to('/');
}
```